# Equivalent for Request.UserHostName in OWIN/Nancy

Tags: c#, .net, nancy, owin

I am trying to return the users host name (not address) in owin.  I am running nancy on top of this.  I know I can use `this.Request.UserHostAddress` to get the IP but I need the name.  I have looked through the API's goggled and I ma struggling to find this information.

The only way I can determine to do this is use the `ASP.NET` `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName` but this won't work when we self host owin and writing code to determine this information depending on how OWIN is hosted seems to defeat the object of OWIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an IP address, you can use [`Dns.GetHostEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143997%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (or moral equivalents) to get a [`IPHostEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iphostentry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object that has a [`HostName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iphostentry.hostname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

That's all that [`UserHostName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) was doing for you anyway (a DNS lookup):

> Gets the DNS name of the remote client.